# Inconsistent behavior between <p:commandLink> and <p:commandButton>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, commandlink, commandbutton

I have a delete confirmation dialog:

```
  <p:confirmDialog id="deleteConfirmDialog"
    header="#{i18n['confirm-deletion']}"
    widgetVar="pnp_delete_confirmDialog" closeable="false"
    appendToBody="true">
    <f:facet name="message">
      <h:outputFormat id="deleteConfirmMessage"
        value="#{i18n['confirm-subscription-deletion']}">
        <f:param value="#{subscriptions.deleteSelected.title}" />
      </h:outputFormat>
    </f:facet>
    <h:form id="pnpConfirmDeleteForm">
      <p:commandButton id="deleteActionConfirmed"
        action="#{subscriptions.delete}" value="#{i18n['delete']}"
        type="button" process="@this" update=":pnpEditForm :pnpExistingForm"
        oncomplete="pnp_delete_confirmDialog.hide()" />
      <p:commandLink id="deleteActionConfirmedLink"
        action="#{subscriptions.delete}" process="@this"
        update=":pnpEditForm :pnpExistingForm"
        oncomplete="pnp_delete_confirmDialog.hide()">#{i18n['delete']}</p:commandLink>
      <p:commandButton id="deleteActionCancelled" value="#{i18n['cancel']}"
        type="button" onclick="pnp_delete_confirmDialog.hide()" />
    </h:form>
  </p:confirmDialog>
```

You will notice that the `deleteActionConfirmed` button and the `deleteActionConfirmedLink` link have the exact same action, process, update, and oncomplete attributes.  However, the link works as expected and the button does nothing.  Looking at the generated markup:

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  action="/primefaces-quickstart/xhtml/pnp-configuration.xhtml" method="post"
  name="pnpConfirmDeleteForm" id="pnpConfirmDeleteForm">
  <input type="hidden" value="pnpConfirmDeleteForm" name="pnpConfirmDeleteForm">
  <button type="button"
    class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"
    name="pnpConfirmDeleteForm:deleteActionConfirmed"
    id="pnpConfirmDeleteForm:deleteActionConfirmed" role="button"
    aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-button-text">Delete</span>
  </button>
  <a
    onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'pnpConfirmDeleteForm:deleteActionConfirmedLink',process:'pnpConfirmDeleteForm:deleteActionConfirmedLink',update:'pnpEditForm pnpExistingForm',oncomplete:function(xhr,status,args){pnp_delete_confirmDialog.hide();}});return false;"
    class="ui-commandlink" href="#"
    id="pnpConfirmDeleteForm:deleteActionConfirmedLink">Delete</a>
  <button type="button" onclick="pnp_delete_confirmDialog.hide();"
    class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"
    name="pnpConfirmDeleteForm:deleteActionCancelled"
    id="pnpConfirmDeleteForm:deleteActionCancelled" role="button"
    aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-button-text">Cancel</span>
  </button>
  <input type="hidden" autocomplete="off"
    value="7076449462381240234:-2976764560029615800" id="javax.faces.ViewState"
    name="javax.faces.ViewState">
</form>
```

You can see that there is no onclick generated for the button, where there is for the link.  Am I missing something or is this a bug in primefaces?  If a bug, is there a workaround other than using links with styles to make them look like buttons?

I am using mojarra 2.1.14 with primefaces 3.4.2 on tomcat 6.0.32 (servlet 2.5, el 2.1).

Answer (score 3):

ARGH...  Simple mistake.  The type attribute of the `p:commandButton` determines the behavior.  It appears that by setting `type='button'` I have turned it into a (taken from the primefaces user guide):

> **Push Buttons**
>
> Push buttons are used to execute custom javascript
>   without causing an ajax/non-ajax request. To create a push button set
>   type as "button".
>
> `<p:commandButton type="button" value="Alert"
>   onclick="alert(‘Prime’)" />`

Switching type to submit fixed this issue.  Lesson learned...  If using buttons, `type='button'` causes the component to ignore any server side `action`.

Comment: Or just remove the `type` attribute. It defaults to the right one already.

Comment: @BalusC, that is actually what I did.  Thanks for the input.  Just seems weird that the `action` attribute gets ignored if `type='button'`.  Would be nice if it either detected that action was present and automatically changed type to submit, or logged a warning or threw an exception indicating that its not gonna do what you are trying to do...

Comment: Report to PF guys if necessary.